# Difference in compiling C code in 32-bit and 64-bit with -m32 option in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, nasm, 32bit-64bit, buffer-overflow

Here I am trying to buffer overflow a very simple C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        /* [1] */ char buf[256];
        /* [2] */ strcpy(buf,argv[1]);
        /* [3] */ printf("Input:%s\n",buf);
        return 0;
}`
```

On my Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit virtual machine I compile it with the following command (I did disable ASLR before compiling) :

```
gcc -g -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o vuln vuln.c -m32
```

And the result assembly code is:

```
   0x0804843b <+0>:     lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   0x0804843f <+4>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048442 <+7>:     pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
   0x08048445 <+10>:    push   %ebp
   0x08048446 <+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048448 <+13>:    push   %ecx
   0x08048449 <+14>:    sub    $0x104,%esp
   0x0804844f <+20>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x08048451 <+22>:    mov    0x4(%eax),%eax
   0x08048454 <+25>:    add    $0x4,%eax
   0x08048457 <+28>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x08048459 <+30>:    sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x0804845c <+33>:    push   %eax
   0x0804845d <+34>:    lea    -0x108(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048463 <+40>:    push   %eax
   0x08048464 <+41>:    call   0x8048310 <strcpy@plt>
   0x08048469 <+46>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x0804846c <+49>:    sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x0804846f <+52>:    lea    -0x108(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048475 <+58>:    push   %eax
   0x08048476 <+59>:    push   $0x8048510
   0x0804847b <+64>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x08048480 <+69>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x08048483 <+72>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x08048488 <+77>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ecx
   0x0804848b <+80>:    leave  
   0x0804848c <+81>:    lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
   0x0804848f <+84>:    ret
```

Unfotunately in the tutorial whose OS is Ubuntu 12.04 (x86) it generated a different code:

```
   0x08048414 <+0>:     push   %ebp                      //backup caller's ebp
   0x08048415 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp                 //set callee's ebp to esp

   0x08048417 <+3>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp          //stack alignment
   0x0804841a <+6>:     sub    $0x110,%esp               //stack space for local variables
   0x08048420 <+12>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax            //eax = argv
   0x08048423 <+15>:    add    $0x4,%eax                 //eax = &argv[1]
   0x08048426 <+18>:    mov    (%eax),%eax               //eax = argv[1]
   0x08048428 <+20>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)            //strcpy arg2 
   0x0804842c <+24>:    lea    0x10(%esp),%eax           //eax = 'buf' 
   0x08048430 <+28>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)               //strcpy arg1
   0x08048433 <+31>:    call   0x8048330 <strcpy@plt>    //call strcpy
   0x08048438 <+36>:    mov    $0x8048530,%eax           //eax = format str "Input:%s\n"
   0x0804843d <+41>:    lea    0x10(%esp),%edx           //edx = buf
   0x08048441 <+45>:    mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)            //printf arg2
   0x08048445 <+49>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)               //printf arg1
   0x08048448 <+52>:    call   0x8048320 <printf@plt>    //call printf
   0x0804844d <+57>:    mov    $0x0,%eax                 //return value 0
   //Function Epilogue
   0x08048452 <+62>:    leave                            //mov ebp, esp; pop ebp; 
   0x08048453 <+63>:    ret                              //return
```

Why are there such huge differences in the prologue and the epilogue? Any documents and explanation is appreciated.

And as I tried, overflowing the former asm code didn't yield any result. Is that because of some security features of newer version of Ubuntu?
P.s: Sorry for the length of the question, I have no other choice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Different versions of the compiler generate different machine code. Shouldn't be too surprising. Looks like the big change happened around GCC 4.9. In 4.9 and later, you get output that looks like yours. Prior to 4.9, you get output that looks like the tutorial's. Passing `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2` helps trim some of the fat in modern versions, but obviously also changes the behavior. Not sure what you're really asking here. This has nothing to do with the version of Ubuntu and everything to do with the version of the compiler. You can downgrade to a previous version if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you that part of answers my questiosn! But I'm still wondering why the first code have to use ecx? If it is to recover esp we have ebp right?

Comment: It can use whatever register it wants to use! This is just what the optimizer decided to do.